# Chrome Developer Tools: Way to temporarily ignore or disable all debugger keywords

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to temporarily ignore or disable all debugger keywords, but then re-enable them at once?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your `debugger` in a function.

```
var d = function() {
  debugger; // comment-out as needed
};


d();
```

There's also the **Never pause here** feature for skipping over individual lines of code (although this question was about batch disabling debugger statements). Right-click on the code line column to access it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kayce. I could not find "Never pause here" option in chrome in Windows.

Comment: @vineel Shows up for me, on Windows 10 with Chrome 59.

Comment: This also worked for me in Chrome 59! More uses for never pause here: https://medium.com/p/never-pause-here-undoing-breakpoints-in-chrome-devtools-97e64cd06086

Comment: Sadly doesn't work for my situation where the code keeps making new instances of debugger()

Answer (score -1):

Workaround is just to comment them out using “Find and replace all” `debugger;` keywords.

That feature or way to temporarily disable debugger keywords probably won't be happening too.

You can read that through this Chrome bug [post](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=6&q=skip%20line%20while%20debugging&id=382904&thanks=382904&ts=1402405661#hc6)